# How to make community visualization in Google Data Studio to be purchased by user before using it

Tags: looker-studio

Is it possible in Google Data Studio community visualization that my custom visualizations are only available for some trial period and after trial period user(s) have to purchase the visuals? If it is possible how can I do it in google data studio community visualization?

Answer (score 0):

That's not currently possible - but we are looking at ways to facilitate future monetization of the visualizations.